# What does a zero value coalesce function do?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbt

I have been exploring dbt tools and I came across the following code snippet :

`coalesce(customer_orders.number_of_orders, 0) as number_of_orders`

I understand that a coalesce function is used to return the first non-null value in a list. What I do not understand is what does the zero in the second parameter signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**COALESCE**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) function returns the first non-null value in a list. `COALESCE` can take n number of arguments.

```
COALESCE(val1, val2, ...., val_n)
```

So according to the query:

```
coalesce(customer_orders.number_of_orders, 0) as number_of_orders
```

In case `customer_orders.number_of_orders` is `NULL` the result returned in `number_of_orders` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` can use as many arguments as you want. In most cases (like in your example), `COALESCE(some_column,0)` is used to prevent that creating a sum or building an average will not lead to the desired result.

Assume there are three columns and you want to sum them. In case you don't use `COALESCE`, the sum will be `NULL`even if only one of your three columns is `NULL`. So you will use `COALESCE`and replace `NULL` values by zero in order to receive the sum of all `NOT NULL` values.
You can "translate" `COALESCE` into a `CASE WHEN` construct:

```
COALESCE(column1,0)
```

does following:

```
CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE column1 END
```

Another use case of `COALESCE` is to replace column1 by column2 if column1 is `NULL`, if also column2 is `NULL`, take column3 etc.
I created an example here, so you can see what I mean:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff21b133a3a8c74673044462f7a110df)